# Used the same code as given in Android's Jetpack's CameraX documentation, but PreviewView is not found

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I'm trying to integrate camerax into my app. I followed the official documentation given [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture#model-example). In the example code the second line mentions:

```kotlin
val viewFinder: PreviewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView)
```

But `PreviewView` is not found. I went to the official class definition documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView) and found that the hierarchy is `androidx.camera.view.PreviewView`. So I tried adding it explicitly

```kotlin
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
```

But `androidx.camera.view` is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PreviewView` [was added to `androidx.camera:camera-view`](https://androidx.tech/packages/androidx.camera.view#PreviewView) starting with version `1.0.0-alpha04`. So, make sure
that your CameraX dependencies in Gradle are at `1.0.0-alpha04` and that you have `androidx.camera:camera-view` as one of those dependencies.